# How to increase Video Memory in Assasins Creed Syndicate

Tags: assassins-creed-syndicate

Ok, so I just bought AC Syndicate and when I launch it the game has 2fps. So I goto the settings and this is here.

[image]

And these are my specs.

[image]

Is there A detection issue or does my PC just suck?

Comment: What GPU does your PC have?

Comment: @Nzall it's right there in his screenshot: "intel hd graphics 4400" an integrated chipset.

Comment: @TrentHawkins I missed that, sorry. It might have been that he has a discrete GPU in his PC from a main brand like Nvidia or AMD and just plugged his monitor into the wrong port.

Comment: @Nzall That's more likely, GTA 4 can't detect my dedicated video card as well.

Comment: AC: Syndicate can detect Intel HD 4400.  ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PA_ZW4TmkmE ). Did you try reinstall AC? But minimal configuration (of GPU) is: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 or AMD Radeon R9 270 (2GB VRAM with Shader Model 5.0)

Comment: An HP 500-267c only has an integrated video card.  Your computer doesn't meet the specs needed to play the game, which is why you're getting such bad framerates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the only game that you're having issues with, AC Syndicate is grabbing the wrong video card. You need to manually assign AC to use your dedicated graphics card. I'm going to assume you have a Nvidia card for now, leave a comment if it's AMD instead.

- Right click on your screen and select NVidia settings
- Click manage 3d settings
- You get a list of all programs found on your laptop (AC Syndicate might not me listed, in that case, click ADD next to list and browse to where the ACS.exe is located)
- Force it to use your dedicated graphics card.
- Click apply

Comment: How do ik if its nvida or amd ?

Comment: @TomRibbertry What are your options when you right-click on your desktop?

Comment: @Riley but does he has a nvidia/amd graphic card?